# Execute commands before exiting WinDbg

Tags: windbg

Is there a way to execute commands before WinDbg exits?

In particular I'd like to do a `.write_cmd_hist <filename>` to save all the commands I used during the debug session so that I can more easily remember what I did in case anyone asks how I did the analysis.

**Approach 1**

I tried redefining the `q` command, but the following does not work, and of course it would only work if WinDbg is not closed by menu:

`aS q ".write_cmd_hist c:\hist.txt; q"` tries to replace `q` again.

`aS q ".write_cmd_hist c:\hist.txt; qq"` gives Syntax error when doing `q`. Backslash got lost.

`aS q ".write_cmd_hist c:\\hist.txt; qq"` gives Syntax error when doing `q`.

`aS q ".block{.write_cmd_hist c:\hist.txt; qq}"` backslash got lost

`aS q ".block{.write_cmd_hist c:\\hist.txt; qq}"` gives Syntax error when doing `q`.

`aS q ".block{.write_cmd_hist "c:\\hist.txt"; qq}"` is malformed string

`aS q ".block{.write_cmd_hist \"c:\\hist.txt\"; qq}"` gives Syntax error. .write_cmd_hist does not like quotes.

`aS q ".block{.block{.write_cmd_hist c:\\hist.txt};qq}"` gives Syntax error when doing `q`.

**Update**

It seems like .write_cmd_hist [cannot be used in aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN) and [cannot be used in scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN). This also applies to other commands mentioned in that article, e.g.

```
aS ccc .cls
```

When doing `ccc` now, it also displays a syntax error.

**Is there any other way to execute scripts when exiting WinDbg?**

Comment: .write_cmd_hist is a command implemented in windbg.exe, not in the debug engine, so cannot alias it, and cannot use it in script. I have similar requirement and hooked the AddCommand method in windbg and records every input commands to a log file, launching windbg also adds the commands in previous log file to the command history. Wish this will be supported officially.

Comment: @Thomson: that sounds more like debugging WinDbg. Interesting concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to keep a log of all the commands that were executed and their results. I think you should use `.logopen`

Only catch here is that, you have to mention this command upfront, before you begin debugging. Otherwise the commands/results will not be logged.

Comment: I usually do `.logopen` already, but the commands are hard to find in all the output.

Comment: @ThomasWeller did you find a way to execute `.logopen` upon WinDbg launch? I want `.logopen /u /t/ /d` to be executed automatically, when a WinDbg session starts. Thanks!

Comment: @golosovsky: `windbg.exe /c ".logopen /t /u /d"` should work. Make a shortcut which includes the parameters or write a batch file.